# upload with your own name php

Tags: php, upload

I was wondering how to excactly change name while uploading a file.
I have a text input "name", so I tried to put $_POST['name'] to moveuploadedfile function, but with no result. Where exactly should I place it?

html

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php"method="post">

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
        <input type="text" name="watermark" placeholder="watermakr" />
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

php

```
$uploads_dir ='/usr/local/apache/htdocs/images/';
$target_file = $uploads_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
echo "Only JPG, JPEG, PNG files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}



if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "ERROR";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
}
else {


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {



    echo "File". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " was sent.";
```

Comment: You could either change the name of the file after you move it or you could change it as you move it. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Old line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)
```

New line:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploads_dir . $_POST['name'])
```

Comment: it doesn't work, It displays an error from my function checking if you uploaded only jpeg/png file.

Comment: Why change it? This won't work. OP wants to have a custom name for the "file".

Comment: And that custom name is in $_POST['name']. Now he saves the file as $_FILES['file']['name'], so the original name.

Comment: No, if the OP changes that to what you suggest, the file won't upload. Go over the question/code again.

Comment: So you use $target_file for checking? That piece of code is not included in your fragment, and that's my update does not work. In the future: please provide everything that is needed... See my updated code

Comment: @Fred-ii- This code changes the target name, not the original name. It should work if it wasn't that the OP does something weird to check the extension.

Comment: I already tried your updated code. It doesnt work with my check function, which I updated.

Comment: You've changed your answer from your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27984593/1 The OP now needs to try it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "File". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " was sent.";
```

Use

```
    $ext = last(explode('.', $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
    $custom_name = 'something'; // or $_POST['name']
    $imageName = $custom_name.'.'.$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploads_dir . $imageName);
```

Comment: it displays an error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/upload.php on line 81'

line 81 is '$newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp); '

Comment: updated the answer.  See here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory`