# Upload csv file only and rename before saving into database

Tags: php

```
$org_file_name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($org_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$file_path = 'docs/';
$rand = rand(111,999);          
if($ext == 'csv')
{
    if(file_exists($file_path))
    {
         $file_path = 'docs/'.$org_file_name;
    }
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'],$file_path))
    {
        die ('<script> alert("file not uploaded successfully."); </script>');
    }           
}
else
{
    die ('<script> alert("Uploaded only CSV files."); </script>');
}
```

In my code, csv files uploads but it doesn't rename it before saving into the database? I get the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 28 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line 29

How can I rename them? and how can I fetch this file from database.

Comment: Your file path is a directory. You cannot check it with file_exists

Comment: @TamásSzabó `file_exists` also works with directories afaik. that's cause all PHP file operations are handled *nix - style, where directories are files as well.

Comment: Hm. Okay then sorry "Asker", I thought its not. Thanks for information @northkildonan :)

Comment: This could help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory

Comment: Please help to rename file..

Comment: @TamásSzabó you are welcome. i just knew this, because it already gave me a headache in the following situation: when you are checking for a file with `file_exists($path . $filename)` and your `$filename` is empty, it will return `true`.

Comment: @Syed ObaidUllah Naqvi it is not solving my problem.. Giving errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the PHP Docs ([move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)):

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

> (...) If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by
>   destination.

so you just have to change your `$file_path` to the path + filename you want, for example: `documents/csv/myfile.csv`

Comment: please elaborate if you can

Comment: @Elixir i don't know what is still unclear about it.