# Simple PHP Image Move

Tags: php, apache, http, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm attempting to move an uploaded image (from Android) that is to be renamed via the PHP below in the second example so that their names cannot conflict.  The original example below uploads files correctly but can have naming conflicts.  The error that I'm experiencing is that the move_uploaded_files function fails, which I'm unsure as to why.  The directory appears the same but I could be wrong and the problem is that image is never moved from the temp directory.  Above all else, I think this is just a directory issue since the original example works.  Please let me know if you need more information. The example I'm going by is located here: [How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)

Original:

```
$uploaddir = './appphotos/';   
$absPath = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/complaint_desk/appphotos/'; 
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$newName = $uploaddir . $uploadFile;
```

New Attempt:

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);

echo json_encode($temp);
$newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
echo json_encode($newfilename);

$uploadFile = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["name"], "/var/www/complaint_desk/appphotos/" . $newfilename);    echo json_encode($uploadFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the function as follow:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], "./appphotos/" . $newfilename)) {
  echo json_encode($uploadFile); // why do you want to encode it?
} else {
  echo 'File failed to move';
}
```

Always check the result of `move_uploaded_file()`. Also, the file is located at `$_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]` before moving.

---

Also, `$absPath` is incorrect. It shouldn't start with http protocol. It should look like `/var/www/complaint_desk/appphotos/` or `C:/complaint_desk/appphotos/`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It was the directory after all: /var/www/complaint_desk/appphotos/