# Change filename on PHP5 file uploader

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this code for a PHP image-only uploader.

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "cdn/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $file_name =  basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is that image on iPhones are ALL named image.jpeg so when you try to upload an image, it will come out as saying it was already uploaded.

 I need a PHP code that will rename the file when before it is uploaded. I have scoured the internet but nothing has worked. Please help.

**UPDATE:**

I tried using the code from [How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory) But the variables aren't the same, can someone help me fix it so they match the variables I have.

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)

Comment: @Leggendario that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "cdn/uploads/";
    $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], '.'), 1); // extension
    $file_name = md5(time().uniqid()) . '.' .$ext; // unique filename
    $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help. Mark as answered please.