# How to change image file name before uploading to database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to rename the file of image before inserting into database?

- DB name :Project
- Table Name: image
- ields: id (`int`), file (`varchar`) [image url stored here], name (`varchar`) [image description]

HTML Codes GOES HERE

```
<form method="POST" action="signup_process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 Image:  <input type="file" name="user_image">
<input tyoe="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

signup_process.php

```
 <?php
    include 'dbcon.php';
    $filename = $_FILES[user_image][name];
    $source = $_FILES[customer_photo][tmp_name];
    $destination = "photos/$filename";
    move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);

//sql statement bla bla below to upload file in image table

    ?>
```

This script upload the file in photos directory of my seerver but what i want is i want to change that name to corresponding id of my image table .
**for example sunshine.jpg  --> 5.jpg**

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)

Comment: That's too long script ...I need modification in my code.

Comment: Nobody is required to change your code. Your question has already been answered in that link.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please Check below code ,is working for me.

$source = $_FILES[customer_photo][tmp_name];
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["user_image"]["name"]);
$newfilename = rand(1,99999) . '.' .end($temp); //you can change here random id replace the your id
$destination = "photos/$newfilename";    
move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the file name before moving it to it's final location, simply change this line:

```
$destination = "photos/$filename";
```

to this:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["user_image"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
$destination = "photos/<the name you want>." . $extension;
```