# My basic PHP upload and rename file script doesn't work

Tags: php

```
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        rename ("$_FILES.txt", "$_FILES.html");
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

It should rename the file when it's uploaded right?

Here's the full script http://pastebin.com/WAWSk55i

Comment: see this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory - `rename ("$_FILES.txt", "$_FILES.html");` that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this
`rename ($_FILES.txt, $_FILES.html);`