# Upload video file using HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, video, upload

I have been looking for a way to upload videos and photos using HTML and PHP.
I have found this piece and code and it has been working fine, but when I upload things from an iPhone they just upload with the name 'Image'. Is there anyway that if a file with the same name already exists, is will add a number to the end it of so they are not longer the same?

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array(
    "jpg",
    "jpeg",
    "gif",
    "png"
);
$extension   = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || 
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || 
($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && 
($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Also, when I try this with MOV files, it returns an error on line 10. An ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out earlier, the answer to your first quest is found here: [How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)

As Ben Fortune states, you might use

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

As for the second question, whenever you upload a .mov file, the script checks whether the file extension is in `$allowedExts` array, which is defined like this:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
```

What you have to do is to add .mov into it:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mov");
```