# How do I rename a image file name in a file upload script?

Tags: php

I cant figure out how to rename a filename inside the file upload script that I have.

Any help is really appreciated!!

Below is the script I am working on.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "../user_profile_pictures/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType  = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Lo siento, el archivo ya existe.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType !=     "png") {
    echo "Lo siento, solo se permiten imagenes tipo jpg, jpeg o png.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Lo siento, el imagen no se ha subido.";

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "El imagen ". basename( $_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]). " se ha subido.";
    } else {
        echo "Ha habido un error al subir el archivo.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Similar question you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I have added a newname variable to your original code.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "../user_profile_pictures/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]);
$newname = "chosen-name";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType  = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Lo siento, el archivo ya existe.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType !=     "png") {
echo "Lo siento, solo se permiten imagenes tipo jpg, jpeg o png.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Lo siento, el imagen no se ha subido.";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"],  $target_dir.$newname)) {
    echo "El imagen ". basename( $_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]). " se ha subido.";
} else {
    echo "Ha habido un error al subir el archivo.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: That did it!!! Thanks for all the help! I can always count on you guys to continue learning!!

Comment: Glad it helped out

Answer (score 0):

in move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) 
Replace $target_file with the directory and the new file.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"], $directory.$newname.'.'.$extension)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) 
just like this

```
else {
rename($target_file,'newname.txt');
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profile_pic"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "El imagen ". basename( $_FILES["profile_pic"]["name"]). " se ha subido.";
    } else {
        echo "Ha habido un error al subir el archivo.";
    }
```