# How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory in PHP?

Tags: php

I use this Simple upload and resize image on PHP project to do my project.
https://gist.github.com/zeuxisoo/910107/483c7b6082dcc484d7b4cee21aad12650c53e416
but I don't know how to rename the file after upload.
I want to rename file and upload it into server as well as in database. The follow is code:

```
public function run() {
    $total = count($this->files);
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
        if (empty($this->files['name'][$i]) === false) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($this->files['tmp_name'][$i], $this->store_directory.'/'.$this->files['name'][$i]) == false) {
                $this->errors['type'] = "run";
                $this->errors['file_name'] = $this->files['name'][$i];
            }
        }
    }

    return empty($this->errors);
}
```

I use a lot of method , eg basename
It can't to it, any idea?? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)

Comment: Kindly accept any one answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
public function run() {
    $total = count($this->files);
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
        if (empty($this->files['name'][$i]) === false) {

              $tempName = explode(".", $this->files['name'][$i]);
              $newName = "IMAGE_NAME"; //generate unique string to avoid conflict
              $newfilename = $newName . '.' . end($tempName );
            if (move_uploaded_file($this->files['tmp_name'][$i], $this->store_directory.'/'.$newfilename) == false) {
                $this->errors['type'] = "run";
                $this->errors['file_name'] = $this->files['name'][$i];
            }
        }
    }

    return empty($this->errors);
}
```

In `$newName` you can generate new name for your file.

**Update**

To avoid conflict use unique string each time when you generate the name.

Comment: If we use a fixed string like `IMAGE_NAME` as you suggested, there would be a case that if a same file will be uploaded again, then the image with such a name on server will be replaced. So better to use some name convention which will help to avoid such situations. I have taken care of it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `move_uploaded_file` use it as per code example given below.

```
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/imageDirectory/" . $newfilename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

```
public function run(){
    $total = count($this->files);
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        if(empty($this->files['name'][$i]) === false){
            $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($this->files['name'][$i], '.')), 1); //get the extension
            $new_name = 'new-name'.date('dmY').$ext;
            if (move_uploaded_file($this->files['tmp_name'][$i], $this->store_directory.'/'.$new_name) == false) {
                $this->errors['type'] = "run";
                $this->errors['file_name'] = $this->files['name'][$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return empty($this->errors);
}
```