# Rename PDF when upload it PHP

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

So, I have the following code to upload a PDF and i would like to rename it because if it has the same name that already exists it will replace the old one.

Here's my code:

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["pdf_file"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $upload_pdf=$_FILES["pdf_file"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf_file"]["tmp_name"],"anexos/" . $_FILES["pdf_file"]["name"]);
        $querypdf  = "INSERT INTO anexos (pdf_file,id_colaborador) VALUES (?,?)";
        $qpdf = $pdo->prepare($querypdf);
        $qpdf->execute(array($upload_pdf,$id));
        //die(print_r($_FILES));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename uploaded file before saving it into a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the name of the file by changing the name of the file in the second parameter of `move_uploaded_file`.

```
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf_file"]["tmp_name"],"anexos/" . $newfilename);
```

Comment: And then I just need to add a new input field for the user to input the new name?