# Error when changing the upload directory in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to have a file name generated randomly from specific ranges but be unique. I used w3schools to make the upload code and tried modifying it to change it to the generated filename but it fails to upload each time with this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: tiledir in /home/rngsites/public_html/b/upload.php on line 67

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/rngsites/public_html/b/upload.php on line 67

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpGVMrRA' to '' in /home/rngsites/public_html/b/upload.php on line 67
> Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
> I assumed that running the function at the beginning of the document would define the variable by the time upload function is run.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form class='form' action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP (updated):

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
tile();

function tile(){
    $z = rand(1,3);
    if ($z === 1) {
        $x = rand(0,1);
        $y = rand(0,1);
    } elseif ($z === 2) {
        $x = rand(0,3);
        $y = rand(0,3);
    } elseif ($z === 3) {
        $x = rand(0,15);
        $y = rand(0,15);
    }
    $tile = $z.'-'.$x.'-'.$y.'.png';
    $tiledir = 'tiles/'.$tile;
    if (file_exists($tiledir)) {
    tile();
    } else {
        upload();
    }
    }

function upload(){
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "png" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only PNG files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $tiledir)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
}
?>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory) solution earlier and it didn't quite help.

I remember being able to this exact thing several years ago on a different site and it worked. I don't understand what I missed this time around.

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Unless I missed something in the tidy you appear to have an extra `}`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i added the error reporting. 
will update question with the report. but it seems i have an undefined variable

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, a single equals sign (`=`) is assignment, not an equality check. Change your `tile` function to use two or three equals signs instead.

```php
function tile(){
    $z = rand(1,3);
    if ($z === 1) {
        $x = rand(0,1);
        $y = rand(0,1);
    } elseif ($z === 2) {
        $x = rand(0,3);
        $y = rand(0,3);
    } elseif ($z === 3) {
        $x = rand(0,15);
        $y = rand(0,15);
    }
    $tile = $z.'-'.$x.'-'.$y.'.png';
    $tiledir = 'tiles/'.$tile;
    if (file_exists($tiledir)) {
        tile();
    } else {
        upload();
    }
```

Comment: That said, I don't know why `tile()` does work on the file system but doesn't pass it on to `upload()`. I'm guessing that `tile()` is intended to be recursive until it finds a filename that doesn't exist and once it finds a new one, it should pass it to `upload` as the first parameter. The `tile()` randomization thing is eventually going to get slower and slower as files are added, too

Comment: apparently in PHP variable can only be used by the function that makes them. and I have to pass them over in a class or as a global variable. trying to figure out how to do that now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My code, although very inefficient was not wrong. I failed to pass the variables from the functions so what I ended up doing is getting rid of functions and making the whole thing one `big if elseif else` statement.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
tile();
function tile(){
    $z = rand(1,3);
    if ($z === 1) {
        $x = rand(0,1);
        $y = rand(0,1);
    } elseif ($z === 2) {
        $x = rand(0,3);
        $y = rand(0,3);
    } elseif ($z === 3) {
        $x = rand(0,15);
        $y = rand(0,15);
    }
    $tile = $z.'-'.$x.'-'.$y.'.png';
    $tiledir = 'tiles/'.$tile;
    if (file_exists($tiledir)) {
    tile();
    } else {
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "png" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only PNG files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $tiledir)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
}
}
?>
```